# Как установить php-fpm на nginx в Debian 11

Tags: php, nginx, debian, php-fpm, putty

В putty на Debian 11 установила веб-сервер nginx. Теперь мне нужно, установить Интерпретатор PHP и php-fpm. После настроить php-fpm с nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Можете установить из репозитория:

```sh
sudo apt install php-fpm
```